# Creating number patterns in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to create 2 patterns of similar type (in python):

> ```
>   1
>  2 2
> 3 3 3
> ```

and

> ```
>   1
>  2 3
> 4 5 6
> ```

up to a length specified by the user

I have written a code to print the pattern of the 1st type:

```
    def rec1():
        for i in range(0,n,1):
           count=i
           print(" "*(n-i) + str(i+1) + " ",end=" ")
           if count!=0:
               rec2(i+1)
           else:
               print("\n")

    def rec2(x):
        print(str(x) + " ",end=" ")
        count=count-1
        if count>0:
            rec2(x)
        else:
            print("\n")
        return

    count=0
    n=int(input("Number?"))
    rec1()
```

However i am getting the following error:

```
   Number?5
         1  

        2  2  *Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Python34/pattern1.py", line 33, in <module>
        rec1()
      File "C:/Python34/pattern1.py", line 18, in rec1
        rec2(i+1)
      File "C:/Python34/pattern1.py", line 24, in rec2
        count=count-1
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment*
```

Can anyone provide a more efficient code?

Comment: Error is self-explanatory. `count` does not exist in scope of function `rec2`.

Comment: Further to what @Rogalski said, the line `count=count-1' is invalid because count hasn't been declared inside or passed into rec2.

Comment: Thanks. I passed 'count' as an argument from 'rec1()' to 'rec2()' and now it is working. However, i intended to declare it as global. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def rec1(n):
  for i in range(1,n+1,1):
    s = ""
    s += (" "*(n-i))
    for j in range(0,i,1):
        s += (str(i) + " ")
    print(s)

n=int(input("Number?"))
rec1(n)
```

You don't need rec2

Comment: Thanks :)..wish i had thought of that earlier

Comment: Could you help me with the other pattern too?

Comment: Just initialize a counter in `rec1` to value `1`, print it instead of `i` and increment it after each `j range` loop

Answer (score 0):

The following is another approach to generate the first and second pattern:

```
def generate(n, flag = 0):
    """ n: number; 0 is 1st pattern; 1 is 2nd pattern """

    g = [range(1,n+2)[i*(i+1)/2:i*(i+1)/2 +i+1] for i in range((n+2)/2-1)] if flag else \
    [ (i,)*i for i in range(1, n+1)]
    return [' '* range(1,len(g)+1)[::-1][i] + ' '.join([str(j) for j in g[i]]) for i in range(len(g))]

for t in generate(6, 0): print t  # 1st pattern
for t in generate(6, 1): print t  # 2nd pattern
```

Output:

```
        1
       2 2
      3 3 3
     4 4 4 4
    5 5 5 5 5
   6 6 6 6 6 6
     1
    2 3
   4 5 6
```